# How to check if string is available as a value in an Object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a object `menu` of the type `IMenu`.

```
let menu: IMenu[] = [ 
  {restaurant : "KFC", dish:[{name: "burger", price: "1$"}, {name: "french fries", price: "2$"}, {name: "hot dog", data: "1$"}]}, 
  {restaurant : "Chopsticks", dish:[{name: "fried rice", price: "1$"}, {name: "french fries", price: "1$"}, {name: "grilled chicken", data: "2$"}]}, 
  {restaurant : "Crab House", dish:[{name: "fried rice", price: "1$"}, {name: "Crabs", price: "2$"}, {name: "grilled chicken", data: "2$"}]}
]
```

I need to iterate over the object and incase there is 'fried rice' in the dish,  I need to perfrom some operations. Is there a way I can find out if 'fried rice' is available inside an if conditon

```
for (let index in menu)
{
  let restaurant = await menu[index];

  if(<check if restaurant contains 'fried rice'>)
  {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: ① Please provide a [mre] where you either declare `IMenu` or remove it. ② Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nrybzw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: 1. There's no point in using `await` here. 2. You should never use a `for..in` loop on an array. 3. Please format your post in a way that the code is a little easier to read (e.g. without having to horizontally scroll so much).

Comment: This question look like it could be answered by AI. Consider consulting an AI, it has a good change to come up with an answer.

Comment: Are you just looking for the `find()` method on arrays?

Comment: @Dimava Are you joking? There is a chance that an AI answers garbage that beginners could consider correct. Asking an AI about programming is probably the worst you can do.

Comment: Well, the question is closed. ‍♂️ If it ever reopens I'll write up an answer; let me know if that happens.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `find` if there is only one of each in array:

```
for (const {dish} of menu) {
  const found = dish.find(({name}) => name === 'fried rice')
  if(!found) return // do nothing because was not found

  // do something
  found.name = 'new name'
}
```

But if there are many itens with same name:

```
for (const {dish} of menu) {
  for(const currentDish of dish) {
    if(currentDish.name !== 'fried rice') return // do nothing

    // do something
    currentDish.name = 'new name'
  }
}
```